# Help identifying this circuit and understanding how it works

Tags: opto-isolator

So I'm hoping to make a few modifications to my computer case and have found that a number of the LED elements have an associated circuit to them.

I want to be able to understand what I'm doing and not damage the existing components and am looking for some help in identifying and reverse engineering the existing circuitry.

[image]

The board has 4 input pins and 2 outputs.

5V in and 1.7 - 2.1v out to power a red LED.

The resistors read '103' which seem to be 10KΩ resistors.

It appears there is an optocoupler (PC817)

Finally some sort of transistor - probably BJT, but I've no understanding how they work and originally thought it to be a MOSFET.

I have attempted to breakdown the circuit as best I can, but can't imagine that it's correct.

I'd like to make a DIY version of this circuit in order to test my modifications without damaging the original, so any help would be amazing!

Thanks

**Update 1:**

So, I've tried my best to make some sense of this and come up with this very simple schematic, but it lacks the transistor element. I just can't logically work out where it goes. What effect would the lack of the transistor (MOSFET or BJT) have versus the original circuit.

[image]

Comment: BEsides being an overcomplicated LED driver (what else does it do?) and what improvements did you want to make?

Comment: Do you have a real circuit rather than just a cartoon of something that pretends to be a circuit?

Comment: I thought it was a bit complex for what it was doing, but I put it down to the fact it is receiving two signals and outputting one. Ultimatley, I want to replace the RED LEDs with RGB controllable LEDS...but as I'm no expert (barely a novice) I wanted to test off board first and not risk the original component.

Comment: Simple. connect the 5V RGB led string to 5V and drive the RGB inputs however you define first. Rule #1 never try to design something until you specify how it is supposed to work for Inputs and outputs.

Comment: Thanks Tony, that's pretty much what I was thinking needed doing. However in terms of re-producing the existing circuit, I'm still unsure exactly at to the schematic and exact components, any help in this area? Cheers

Comment: Do you have a multimeter? You should be able to trace out the connections on the board using its continuity test mode.